# android imageview scaletype not working for AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-animation

I have a imageview that fills my entire screen and i downloaded images from url into my sdcard, I am using AnimationDrawable to show these images as slideshow in the imageview. But however I try my Images are loosing their aspect ratio, the images appear stretched. I have tried all the scaletype's for my imageview, but no use. Here is my code:

```
    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    File cacheDir = AlRimal.getDataFolder(Main_Load.this);
    File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, "file_1.jpg");
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(cacheFile.getPath());
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cacheFile.getPath());
    animation.addFrame(d, 5000);
    animation.addFrame(d, 5000);
    animation.addFrame(d, 5000);
    animation.setOneShot(false);
    animation.setExitFadeDuration(500);
    animation.setEnterFadeDuration(500);
    animationImg.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);//All possibilities have been tried
    animationImg.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
    animation.start();
```

The resoulution of my images are : 2048*1536

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ScaleType` was not being set because, image in the `ImageView` was set as the background. When I changed it to the source it worked.

Answer (score 3):

instead of

`animationImg.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);`

try to use

```
animationImg.setImageDrawable(animation);
```